# \Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin was unexpected at this time

Tags: html, tailwind-css

my bash keeps giving me \Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin was unexpected at this time. when ever i try to install some files. how do i resolve please.
I tried to run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` on my cmd but keeps ginin me the feedback.

please how do i resolve?

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
\Java\jre1.8.0_192\bin was unexpected at this time.
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project>
```